# How can I apply TDD and BDD in a web application that just collects data from many web services and shows them on screen

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd

Is it overkill to try TDD and BDD in applications in which we consume web services, collect data based on some conditionals, and then show that data on a web page? I am trying to convince my team to use TDD and BDD, but they don't seem to understand the necessity for this.

Comment: As it stands the question is rather broad and unspecific.

Comment: To be specific, suppose I am working on a web application for customer care agents. All this application does, is show data related to users and their services subscribed. However the number of services is large and system is quite big, but the basic functionality is just consuming the web services. Now in this scenario, it seems that I will end up writing trivial tests only. Also I feel that integration test may play an important role here, but unit testing is just too trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Especially for communication across system borders I find automated tests extremely helpful.

Setting up the other system in a way so that it shows the behavior which is required for the test is often rather tedious. With automated tests you'd mock those webservices. With this approach development becomes much faster and easier (after overcomming the learning curve for TDD).

Throw in some tests that test the actual webservices to behave as expected and you get early notification if a change in the webservices is going to break your system.

Comment: I like your last point, which may come in handy because many a times, services change. But I am looking for an example driven explanation of whether TDD or BDD is applicable in this scenario or not.